Auto Call Transcription Twilio
I have an application for call analysis and am using Twilio’s call service with Python. I followed the documentation to enable the call transcription service and configured the necessary attributes via the Python Twilio Client, including specifying a valid endpoint for receiving the webhook.
`import os
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = os.environ["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
auth_token = os.environ["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

service = client.intelligence.v2.services.create(unique_name="UniqueName")

print(service.account_sid)`

`
Although my service is created, I am not receiving the transcription webhook, and Twilio does not seem to be hitting my application endpoint. I have tested my endpoint and confirmed that it is working correctly.
Could you help identify what might be going wrong?
Thank you!
I have tried to create the service both programmatically and manually on Twilio, but neither method worked.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
